# Fill in column into excel with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a report which will get two sets of information, Group name and domain. The problem is that the information will be output into one column instead of two for example:

```
Group Member                   Domain
thisIsGroupMember,Domain
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
Group Member                   Domain
thisIsGroupMember,             Domain
```

I also try export-csv but the created csv file only show

```
Length
32
```

Here's my code:

```
 $appName = $findone.properties.name
 $domain = (($findone.properties.adspath -split ',')[3].substring(3)
 $inputstring = "$appName,$domain"
 out-file -FilePath "C:\Test\Result.csv" -append -inputObject $inputstring
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code iterates through a list of objects pulled from AD you can use something like this:

```powershell
# your foreach code
{
   ...
   $appName = $findone.properties.name
   $domain = (($findone.properties.adspath -split ',')[3].substring(3)
   $output += ,(New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{"Group Member"=$appName;"Domain"=$domain})
}
$output | Export-Csv "C:\Test\Result.csv"
```

`$output` is an array of objects being created on the fly with `$appName` and `$domain` values. It will then nicely export to a csv after all AD objects are processed.